# How to set same width and height of a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a xml layout file in which I have a `Button`. The Height of the `Button` is set as `match_parent`. Now I want the Width to be the same as the Height of the Button to make a square button regardless of changing Height and Width of parent layout..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about this:

```
Button yourBtn = (Button) findViewById.(R.id.yourBtn);

int btnSize=yourBtn.getLayoutParams().width;
yourBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(btnSize, btnSize));
```

Comment: When should this code be called? I call it in `onCreate` but the `btnSize` is -2.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it programmatically. XML layout is only for static stuff.

After the button have been draw at least once on the screen you will resize it by setting a new `LayoutParams` to it with the desired values.