# MaterialButton text not centred after resizing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-gravity

I have a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation that contains 8 `MaterialButton`s with a single digit as the text for each button.

The button has styling:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cellButton"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:insetLeft="0dp"
        android:insetRight="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/foreground"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:cornerRadius="7dp"
    />
```

and the text starts centred as expected.

On the press of a button the final two buttons have their visibility set to `GONE`, leaving only 6 buttons in the row. These buttons no longer have centred text (it is shifted to the left, as if still using the original offset even though the buttons have grown):
[image: a screenshot of buttons with off-centre text with layout bounds shown]

The same thing happens but in reverse (text is off-centre to the right) if I start with 6 buttons in a row and add two more (but the newly-added ones on the end are correct.

The text still becomes off-centre when I:

- switch to using `TextView`s rather than buttons
- also set the `GONE` buttons to have a weight of 0
- call `removeView` on the horizontal `LinearLayout` to remove the hidden buttons rather than just changing their visibility

I have tried resetting the gravity of the buttons when they are clicked (the '2' on the second line was a grey button that was clicked, causing it to have its text/colour set, and the gravity to have been updated to `Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM`), and calling `requestLayout` on the vertically aligned `LinearLayout` containing each row after the appropriate buttons have been hidden, but neither of these had any effect.

Comment: Utilizing a linear layout with a weight sum of 8 for eight buttons, each button is assigned a layout weight of 1, and its width is set to zero. This configuration ensures that each button shares an equal portion of the available width, creating a visually balanced layout. If the need arises to discreetly remove two buttons from view, their visibility can be set to "invisible" while preserving the uniform width distribution across the remaining visible buttons. This approach maintains a cohesive and aesthetically pleasing design even when selectively hiding buttons from the user interface.

Comment: It is desirable for the buttons to resize to fill the available space, as the dataset the view represents (and thus the length of each row) can change when a reset button is pressed. The layout of the buttons is visually perfect, it is just the text position within each button that is at issue

Comment: android:includeFontPadding="false" try this check if it resolve the issue

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies all, it turned out that the problem was that I was using a custom button ([Set button height equal to the button width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701234/set-button-height-equal-to-the-button-width/29702054#29702054)) which messed with the measuring process:

```java
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}
```

Removing this overload solves the issue.